# compare time in awk

Tags: awk

I want to check the modified time of all the files in one directory. If any file has the time different from the current system time, then RED will be printed. Otherwise , GREEN is printed.

```
ls -lrt| grep main | awk '{if ($8 != `date +%R` ) print "-->RED"}END{print"-->GREEN"}'
```

May you suggest me how to correct the above statement. Million thanks.

Comment: Is it 'different' from sytem time? are you sure? Nothing like either less than or greater than system time? Also, what is 'main'? Are you checking for files with name containing main only?

Comment: Yes, I want to search the files with the current system time. My log files updates every second.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You can do what you want with `stat`.

`stat -c%Y file` will output the modification time of a file in seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  `date +%s` will output the current time in seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

So, what you want can be done by:

```
if [[ $(stat -c%Y main) -ne $(date +%s) ]]
then
    echo "RED"
else
    echo "GREEN"
fi
```

If you want the above for a list of files, and output `RED` if any time is different:

```
to_print=GREEN
for f in *main*
do
    if [[ $(stat -c%Y "$f") -ne $(date +%s) ]]
    then
        to_print=RED
        break
    fi
done
echo $to_print
```

If you're not using bash, then you can replace `[[` `]]` pair with `[` and `]`, and `$(...)` with

```
`...`
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean main is keyword

Comment: What do you mean "main is keyword"? You are looking for file names matching "main"?

Comment: Oh yes, then I can modified as follows: 
ls -lrt | awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="date +%R"; cmd| getline current; close(cmd)}{if $8!= current print "RED"}END{print "GREEN"}'
Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way you can do it with shell and date command

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(date +%R)
for file in *main*
do
    d=$(date +%R -r "$file")
    if [ "$d" = "$current" ];then
        echo "GREEN: $file, current:$current, d: $d"
    else
        echo "RED: $file, current: $current, d: $d"
    fi
done
```

note that you will have to adjust to your own needs, since you may just want to compare date only, or time only, etc.. whatever it is, check the man page of date for various date formats.

If you want to do it with awk, here's a pure awk(+GNU date) solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    cmd="date +%R"
    cmd|getline current
    close(cmd)
    for(i=1;i<=ARGC;i++){
        file=ARGV[i]
        if(file!=""){
            cmd="date +%R -r \047"file"\047"
            cmd |getline filetime
            close(cmd)
            if( filetime==current){
                print "GREEN: "file
            }else{
                print "RED: "file
            }
        }
    }
}
' *
```

Comment: Million thanks. I can modify as follows:
ls -lrt | awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="date +%R"; cmd| getline current; close(cmd)}{if $8!= current print "RED"}END{print "GREEN"}'

Comment: as one of the posters mentioned, try not to use `ls -ltr` to parse date. On my system, the hour and min is at $7. Also, `ls` sometimes is aliased so it might not work everywhere. Use stat/date to get time stamp.